# The adjoint oprator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $q$ be a polynomial and $P$ be the vector space of polynomials defined on $ I = [0,1]$ with coefficients from $\mathbb R$ and scalar product $(f,g) = \int _0 ^1 f(t)g(t)dt$. Consider an operator $T:P\rightarrow P $ such that $T(p) = pq$. Find the adjoint operator $T^*$.

Here is what I have so far: I calculate $\langle T f,g \rangle$ = $\int_0^1 (Tf)(t) g(t) dt$. and I got $\langle f,T^* g\rangle$. I got know how to continue. What confuse me is $T(p) = pq$. How do I link $\langle f,T^* g\rangle$ and $T(p)=pq$ to get the adjoint operator $T^*$. Please direct me how to continue. Thanks!

Comment: What is $q$? A scalar, a function?

Comment: q is polynomial. Do you any hints that I could continue?

Answer (score 0):

You have $\langle f,T^*g \rangle = \langle Tf,g \rangle = \int (f q) g = \int f (g q) = \langle f,Tg \rangle$. Hence
$\langle f,T^* g - Tg \rangle = 0$ for all $f$, hence
$T^*g = Tg$ for all $g$, hence $T=T^*$.